# How do I make my PostMapping return an HTML, Thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

So here it's my GetMapping and PostMapping , but when I start my project (tic tac toe) and I select a position to put the symbol, then a page that contains "index" written appears, and then if I refresh to my localhost:8080 it shows the HTML correctly with the modification on the board. Can someone help me pls ? how do I return the HTML with the post ?

```
 @GetMapping("/")
public String home(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("player1",p1);
    model.addAttribute("player2",p2);
    model.addAttribute("board",b);
    return "index";
}
@PostMapping ("/")
@ResponseBody
public String modificar_taulell(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int pos1, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int pos2, Model model){
    char symbol;
    int col,fil;
    if(pos1==0){
        symbol=p2.getSymbol();
        col = (pos2-1)%b.getSize();
        fil= (pos2-1)/b.getSize();
    }
    else{
        symbol=p1.getSymbol();
        col = (pos1-1)%b.getSize();
        fil= (pos1-1)/b.getSize();
    }
    b.getTaulell()[fil][col]= symbol;
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: What do you think `@ResponseBody` does....

Comment: Thank you so much, I just started learning this framework and sometimes it's difficult for me but thanks a lot for answering , now it works !